# UIAutomation for testing 3rd party framework i.e CMPopTipView on an iOS app

Tags: ios6, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I'm running some UIAutomation tests on an iOS app we're developing & have been continuously running into issues mainly while testing 3rd-party frameworks. For eg. the app uses a customized version of chrismiles' CMPopTipView & always returns index[0] irrespective of the cell tapped.

Here is the code snippet:

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[0].tap();

Attached is the screen shot of Tip View cells.Please let me know your suggestions.Thank you.

Regards,[image]
Bhuvana